# Web services authentication with remote IP

Tags: web-services, authentication, remote-access

I’m developing a small application that interacts with a web service which authorizes access based on the client IP. When developing on my local machine at home, I am not allow to access the web service, unless I request an authorization for the random IP that i get from my ISP.

**My question**: Is there an easy way to get around this problem, since I cannot have a fixed IP at home? Proxy, vpn, etc... through a webserver with an authorized IP? How?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is your problem: You can only connect to remote_system from Authorized_IP system.

If you can ssh to Authorized_IP from your home PC, you can setup a ssh tunnel that forward connection to port 8080 of Authorized_IP to the port 80 of the remote_system with ssh command.    If you run Linux on the Authorized_IP system, it is very simple.   Windows is more complex with Cygwin sshd, it is possible.

http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly my problem. I got a Linux machine with an authorized IP so this approach should not be difficult. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: Dynamic DNS.  For testing, point your web service at a hostname that your get from a dynamic DNS provider such as http://dyndns.org.  Then download a tool that automatically updates your DNS entry with your dynamically assigned IP address.

But more to the point, why can't you just use your localhost (127.0.0.1) as your IP address for developing, debugging, testing?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The web service detects the IP provided by the ISP, not the local machine IP address.

Comment: Sorry to sound lame, but after testing dyndns.org and consulting their KB I didn’t figure out how tunnel the HTTP request through a static IP; the hostname provided by dyndns.org uses my (dynamically updated) internet IP Address.

Comment: where is the web service?  what is the client?  what is your local machine IP?  what operating system are you using?